# Eclipse Bash Editor integrated debugger install problem

Tags: bash, eclipse, debugging, scripting, editor

I successfully installed the Bash Editor into a minimal Eclipse, but have not been able to get to the debugger despite that the documents says the debugger is integrated into the Eclipse Bash Editor.

I'm sure I'm only missing a few small particulars to get it working.  So what are they?

In all the tutorials and videos I've seen, it shows a Debug entry under the Bash Editor in Preferences, however in my installation that entry is missing.  I haven't been able to coordinate the problem with any answer.

Here is my Configuration information:

[image: Preferences without Debug item]

THE PARTICULAR INSTALLATION DETAILS

1. I have only the minimal Eclipse installed.
2. Instead of cmd, I would like to use either Powershell, or cygwin64 terminal, but don't know if these are hidden compatibility issues in trying to these with the Bash Editor Debugger.
3. I would like to use either the following 64x bash shells, but the 32 bit github shell was recommended.  I have:

   ./cygwin64/bin/bash.exe
   ./Windows/WinSxS/amd64_microsoft-windows-lxss..../bash.exe

To guide your kind help, please understand I have age related special needs.

At age 75, I"m slowing down, and being isolated, many problems are simple that a 5 minute conversation would solve. But it has been more than 10 years since I have had hardly any of those kinds of conversations, and none about Eclipse, the Bash Editor, and the Debugger.

So far I sorted things out from scratch, and now I am stuck.

Without any touch points sometimes it takes me all day to sort out context and boundary conditions of even simple considerations and particulars I need to know.

Today's environment is not very enabling.  Before the Internet, I can remember a time when I could pick up the phone and get just about any Engineer I wanted to in Silicon Valley.  Now days, that sort of thing seems to be frowned upon.  That dynamic is very new to me, I'm scratching my head over that one.

So if we can get at the particulars I need that would be very helpful.

Sincerely, JS

Answer (score 1):

The preference page ***Bash Editor > Debug*** ([mentioned in the documentation here](https://github.com/de-jcup/eclipse-bash-editor/wiki/Debugger#configuration)) became ***Bash Editor > Launch*** (since it also contains *Run* preferences).